# Where is tokenHandler in Pushwoosh's Phonegap Build example?

Tags: cordova, pushwoosh

According to the example here, step 4:-

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/ios-push-notification-sdk-for-phonegap/

It says "Modify tokenHandler callback from Phonegap Push Plugin (replacing “YOUR_PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID” of course)"

Modify. Suggesting there's something to begin with to modify. Neither PushNotification.js (link below)

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/www/PushNotification.js

Nor the other pushwoosh code, pushwoosh.js

Contain any such code to modify. Any ideas as to where this is?

Answer (score 0):

You could find tokenHandler in PushPlugin example:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/Example/www/index.html

May I ask why don't you use Pushwoosh Phonegap Build plugin? It has much more functionality than GenericPush plugin.

This sample is a "ready-to-go" app for Phonegap Build with Pushwoosh plugin integrated:

https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-3-sample-app

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I'd actually paid an agency to sort this out for me, but I will go back and try and see if I can get this working. I'm not sure if I'd seen your example before - there seems to be loads of slight variants on GitHub and some of them for sure don't compile at all in PhoneGap Build.